# How to aggregate texts and metadata from subunits to larger units?

Tags: r, text

I have a dataframe of paragraphs from within speeches. I would like to combine the row-level data from paragraphs to speech level, concatenating the paragraph text and keeping the metadata. For example, my data looks like this, where index is the value I want to aggregate on:

```
text <- c("cat", "dog", "rabbit", "bird")
pet <- c("y", "y", "n", "n")
index <- c(1, 1, 2, 2)
para <- seq(1:4)

orig <- data.frame(text, pet, index, para)
```

And I would like to transform it to look like this:

```
ideal <- c("cat dog", "rabbit bird")
ideal_pet <- c("y", "n")
index <- seq(1:2)
ideal <- data.frame(ideal, ideal_pet, index)
```

If I `group_by` I won't be able to concatenate the text strings together- my sense is that a loop over the rows would be the way to go?

Comment: You can use a `group_by` you just need a collapsing strategy for each column. Are you collapsing by index? Then `orig %>% group_by(index) %>% summarize(ideal=paste(text, collapse=" "), ideal_pet=first(pet))` should work

Comment: ooh thank you- is ```first``` something like ```slice```?

Comment: You can find the help page using `?first`. It just takes the first value. It's unclear what you would want to happen if there were different pet values for a given index.